# Convert Map to Sorted List

Tags: java, collections, guava

I'm trying to convert a `Map` to an ordered `List` based upon the values in the `Map`.

Suppose I have the following:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Maps.newHashMap();
map.put("foo", 1);
map.put("boo", 3);
map.put("bar", 2);

//list needs to be sorted by Integer Value -- ASC or DESC
List<String> list = //Elegant guava call? List should be: {foo, bar, boo}
```

Comment: I suppose sorted by Integer value -- desc or asc. I'll make it more clear

Comment: @BlueBullet the question clearly states that he wants to order by the *values*, i.e. the integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<String> list = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(map))
   .sortedCopy(map.keySet());
```

...I think?

Comment: How does this order based on the value?

Comment: I realized that didn't order based on the value...and then people upvoted me twice anyway.  But fixed, now.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: this is great. You made me discover two great Guava methods I had not discovered yet. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, I still wish we had made more progress on [this more general Guava issue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=953), but this code is perfectly sufficient if you only care about the keys.

Comment: that's pretty slick -- I'll try it out